# How Collections.sort works when we returns the same value always from compare or compareTo method

Tags: java, collections, comparator, comparable

Consider this code below :

```
class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>{

    int id;

    public Employee(int i) {
        this.id=i;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employee other) {
        return -1;
    }

    public String toString() {

        return String.valueOf(id);
    }   
}

public class S13_0 {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         List<Employee> list=Arrays.asList(new Employee(40),new Employee(67),new Employee(32));
         Collections.sort(list);
         System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

In this code we are simply using the employee objects list with id's [40,67,32]
 and made the employee comparable.
 now i know already that how comparable generally works.
 but i just wanted to know in this case when we return -1(negative integer value)
 irrespective of the input then how sort method gets applied to the list and prints the list
 in reverse order.

```
Output is : [32, 67, 40]
```

Comment: It works poorly

Comment: It uses `compareTo()` to determine what should be the order of list.

Comment: yes i agree that it works poorly but the question is why it always prints the list in reverse order ?

Answer (score 3):

You are "lucky" the `sort()` didn't throw `IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!`

The "general contract" it refers to is documented in the javadoc of [`Comparable.compareTo(T o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-):

> The implementor must ensure `sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x))` for all `x` and `y`. (This implies that `x.compareTo(y)` must throw an exception iff `y.compareTo(x)` throws an exception.)
>
> The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive: `(x.compareTo(y)>0 && y.compareTo(z)>0)` implies `x.compareTo(z)>0`.
>
> Finally, the implementor must ensure that `x.compareTo(y)==0` implies that `sgn(x.compareTo(z)) == sgn(y.compareTo(z))`, for all `z`.

Your code is violating the first rule.

As such, the result of the sort is *undefined*.

Comment: Good answer.  I would remove the "lucky" part - the added complexity of checking that the contract is never violated - at least for this case - isn't worth the small benefit.  In cases of simple checks, like "argument must not be null", the check is simple enough, and the value high enough, that it is worth implemenating.

Comment: @ash I've seen that error. The TimSort implementation *may* throw the error (hence "lucky" it didn't) if it detects inconsistency in the result of `compareTo`. I wasn't referring to something the sort *should* do, but to something it already does. See source code: [TimSort.java line 773](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/43cb25339b55/src/share/classes/java/util/TimSort.java#l773)

Comment: Interesting.  I haven't dug into those internals.  Is TimSort used by `Collections.sort()`?

Comment: @ash `Collections.sort()` calls `List.sort()` calls `Arrays.sort()` calls `TimSort.sort()` *(for natural sort)* or `ComparableTimSort.sort()` *(for Comparator sort)* or `Arrays.mergeSort()` *(if system property `java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort` is `true`)*, so generally yes (in Java 11).

Comment: That depends on the point of view. Getting an exception with a clear message explaining to you the bug of your software, is what I’d call “lucky”, compared to getting an undefined result which may even appear to look as intended during tests…

Comment: @Holger There is a reason I quoted "lucky", because it's a matter of opinion whether it is good or bad luck. Whether you get the exception or not is purely a matter of chance, it is certainly not guaranteed, hence related to "luck". The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) simply says: *Throws `IllegalArgumentException` (optional) if the implementation **detects** that the natural ordering of the list elements is found to violate the `Comparable` contract". Never claims to *validate*. Just *detect*.

Answer (score 0):

Returning a fixed value from the comparison violates the contract.  Therefore, the results are undefined, and implementation-dependent.

If you want to know why you get certain results with a specific implementation, digging through that implementation to understand exactly how it works is the only solution.

Comment: Almost. Always returning zero would be within the contract.